# Problems installing geopandas

Tags: installation, geopandas

I am trying to install geopandas. If I use the function "import geopandas" in Spyder I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'"

I searched online and found that I have to install it from the prompt of windows. So, I tried with this:
"pip install geopandas". I get an error when it starts collecting fiona:

Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/be/04/31d0a6f03943b1684f32c9b861be40c1fd282468fa6bd54ddf4a774e6b0f/Fiona-1.8.13.tar.gz

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\eleon\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\eleon\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9xsna2kr\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\eleon\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9xsna2kr\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
     cwd: C:\Users\eleon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9xsna2kr\fiona\
Complete output (1 lines):
A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have added conda to the path and now I get a connection error. I get it independently on the the library I try to install (I have tried geopandas but also shapely. I have also tried conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas, but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you show the error?

Comment: Actually, I solved this problem (I do not remember how, since I tried several solutions). Now geopandas is installed, but I used an additional environment because there were conflicts. My current problem is how to tell spyder to import geopandas from the not default environment. I suppose it is something really easy but I am not finding the command anywhere!

Comment: I would recommend you to ask a new question specifically about that